# Ajax HTTP-request url not correct

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony-1.4

Following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">      
    function goForLogin() {
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","/account/login",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("email=test%40test.com&password=1");
            }
</script>
```

I run this code in module test/index - I have to!

When I log the request with tampadata, the url is `http://dev.server.com/test/account/login`. How can I get rid of `test` in the url? Two times a different module. This is not correct!

When I do in xmlhttp.open... "dev.server.com/account/login/" The output will be: `http://dev.server.com/test/dev.server.com/account/login/`.

Comment: Did you try `http://dev.server.com/account/login/`? I'm just wondering if an absolute path would work

Comment: Stupid, that's it. Sometime I don't get it but thanks a lot!

Comment: Well I don't think that's a solution! We now know it works, but what happens if you can't produce an absolute path? People rely on relative paths, both starting with "/" and not, which **should** produce different results. In my opinion, using "/account/login" should produce "dev.server.com/account/login", while using "account/login" should produce "dev.server.com/test/account/login" - because of the way URLs should be resolved. And I think both of those are true with a `<form>`'s `action` attribute and `<a>`'s `href` attribute, so why not here?

Comment: I'd like to call it a bug, but maybe there's a reason... I'll see if I can reproduce in a jsFiddle and let you know

Comment: Unrelated - you may want to implement the `onreadystatechange` method of `XMLHttpRequest` to get the response of the AJAX call - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: How can I not implement onreadystatechange? So I can use it in an native app?

Comment: What do you mean "not implement onreadystatechange"? You have to implement it in order to receive the response from your "/account/login" request. For example, if you need to verify that the login was successful (since the username/password may not be correct), you need to see how the server responds. What do you mean "in a native app"?

Comment: No sorry, I got now! Thanks! My fault!

Comment: Ahh unless you mean what is says on the link I posted? It says "This must not be used from native code. You should also not use this with synchronous requests." which I'm not sure what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify a full url as your POST request target:

```
http://dev.server.com/account/login
```